# Converting a file to Base64 to embed in XML file (to show as and attachment in InfoPath)

Tags: xml, binary, base64, attachment

If I look inside of an MS Infopath XML file, the atttachments appear to be look something like: stu2zAQvBfIPwi8BhadFCiKwnIOSXNMA8QFeqWptUWYr5Lr1P77rqg4MQLHimoCzUWURHJmdpaPnVxtjC4eI

I'm told this is Base64.

However, if I go to https://www.browserling.com/tools/file-to-base64 and convert a PDF file, take the result and throw it into an XML tag meant for attachments and then open that file using InfoPath, nothing is displayed where I'd expect to see a file icon. There are no errors, but clearly something is wrong.

What am I missing? What else besides encoding the file do I need to do in order for InfoPath to recognize it?

Answer (score 0):

Probably because when you convert it into the normal, the data is in PDF format and it may not be able to interpret it. Do you have some programming knowledge? I was thinking to read the XML using a C# program, extract the BASE64 data, decode it and write to a file and you should be able to open it as a PDF.